# Change attribute ordering in Magento's advanced search page

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a few custom attributes on my products in Magento and they are searchable in Magento's search page; problem is that the fields are listed in the wrong order on the search page;

For example:

```
Title  _____
Author _____
SKU    _____
ISBN   _____
```

Should be:

```
Author _____
Title  _____
ISBN   _____
SKU    _____
```

I've taken a look at the template file and it seems to be outputting an array (or object) from it's internal ordering. I would like to know how to change this ordering :).

Any (relatively straight-forward) ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you open the Block that matches your template (`catalogsearch\advanced\form.phtml` -> `Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Form`), you will see that it's calling the `getAttributes` method of `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Advanced` which in turn is executing:

```
$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
            ...
            ->setOrder('main_table.attribute_id', 'asc')
            ->load();
```

All of which means that it's sorting by the `attribute_id` field in the `eav_attribute` table, not a particular useful field.

However, the actual query performs a join on the `catalog_eav_attribute` table as `additional_table` which means that you could alter the sort portion of the code to be `->setOrder('additional_table.position', 'asc')` and then change the values of the "position" field in that table via phpMyAdmin.

In order to make this alteration in a future-proof manner, take a copy of the `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Advanced` file and copy it to `app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model` before making any alterations.

To debug the SQL query, turn on `$_debug` and `$_logAllQueries` in `lib/varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php`.  Don't forget to turn that off in production!!

Hope this helps,
JD

Comment: @Jonanthan:I hate such things to do.But magneto is not that much smart on such things.anyway you saved my time.thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 1.7x this can be done through the management of the Product Attribute Set.

Go to Catalog-> Attributes -> Manage Attribute Set --- Select Your Attribute Set

From there you can reorder, add and remove attributes for a set.

Comment: On 1.9x it changes order of attributes on product page not in advanced search

Answer (score 0):

Tried setting the position attribute on those attributes?

Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes -> Attribute -> Frontend Properties -> Position

Edit:

Actually, it looks like you may have to apply manual sorting to the search results block/template.

Start here for details on how to do that kind of thing: http://alanstorm.com/category/magento

Comment: from magento IRC: Position of attribute in layered navigation block is referring to when the attribute is a Dropdown, Select or Price the position is actually in the is_anchor navigation or something similar. So, if the attribute is just a text input, then the position is disabled.